# Using renderLeaflet() inside an interactive document (Rmarkdown)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to create an [interactive document](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/interactive-docs.html) like the tutorial on Shiny's website. However, I want the plot to be a Leaflet map. Following the [Leaflet tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html), it seems like the following should work using `leaflet::renderLeaflet()` instead of `shiny::renderPlot()`.

Instead, I get an error when running the document: `Error: object 'input' not found`. Is there a special way to expose `input` to leaflet when using Shiny widgets inside an interactive Rmarkdown document?

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---


```{r echo = FALSE}
library(magrittr)
shiny::selectInput(
  "weight", label = "Weight:",
  choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), selected = 5
)
```

```{r include = FALSE}
csa <- tigris::combined_statistical_areas(class = "sf")
```

```{r echo = FALSE}
leaflet::renderLeaflet({   # <- main difference from tutorial
  leaflet::leaflet() %>%
    leaflet::addTiles() %>%
    leaflet::addPolylines(data = csa, color = '#333', weight = input$weight)
})
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't confirm your issue. Your sample interactive document runs just fine:

[image]

I've been using the following library versions on R 3.6.1

- `leaflet_2.0.2`
- `rmarkdown_1.16`
- `shiny_1.4.0`

Comment: Very odd. I updated all these packages to the same versions you've listed or better, and still the same error. I'll try updating my R version.

Comment: Updating R to at least 3.6.1 was the key.